# How to stop re-logins in after each test (Cypress-Angular)?

Tags: angular, integration, cypress

I don't want it to login in each time I write a test. When I write "it (cypress)" more than once, it goes back and does a re-login, which I don't want it to happen.

It logins, and after the first test pass, it goes on second test but it does a second login to do the "second it" test. How can I stop it?

```
describe('Integration Tests', function () {
  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.login()
  })
  it('first it', function () {
    cy.get('.css-vj8t7z')
    cy.get('.css-1ep9fjw')
  })
  it('second it', function () {
    cy.get('.css-1ep9fjw')
  })
```

Comment: After login once you could probably get a token, cookie and save that `localStorage`then you don't need to login again to run remaining test. I am following same, but bit more complex approach in my test framework.

Comment: Once after login, press F12 navigate to `Application` tab and see what is available under `Storage > Local Storage`

Comment: @soccerway how did you do that?

Comment: You might not need that complexity, since in my project i have got `single sign on` enabled. So I have to installed puppeteer and created a login script and the put that in root folder. Then called the script via 'package.json' and it will create a `tokendata.json, cookie.json` file and move that to fixture folder. Now in my commands.js file I wrote a function to read the tokendata.json file and set to `window.localStorage.setItem(key, data[key]);` ..this function `cy.loadToken()` will be called in `beforeEach()`

Comment: In that way I have avoided multiple login call

Comment: Did you try just using `before()` which runs only once for all tests in the current context (i.e within the `describe()`). Can't see the need to store anything.

Comment: Thanks, before() works but now I am receiving a 400 error which I think token expiring

Comment: 'receiving a 400 error` - may be a token error, but according to some refs that should  be a 401 (Unauthorized) error.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
  Cypress.LocalStorage.clear = function (keys, ls, rs) {
    return;
```

```
describe('Integration Tests', function () {
  before(() => {
    LocalStorage.clear();
    cy.login()
  })
  it('first it', function () {
    cy.get('.css-vj8t7z')
    cy.get('.css-1ep9fjw')
  })
  it('second it', function () {
    cy.get('.css-1ep9fjw')
  })
```

Answer (score 4):

First find out the cookie it used to login.

Then try some code like below

```
describe('Integration Tests', function () {

  before('login once', function () {
    cy.login()
  }

  beforeEach('keep using the session', function () {
    Cypress.Cookies.preserveOnce("YourCookie")
  })

  it('first it', function () {
    cy.get('.css-vj8t7z')
    cy.get('.css-1ep9fjw')
  })
  it('second it', function () {
    cy.get('.css-1ep9fjw')
  })
```

read more [here](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/cookies.html)

Comment: how do I get my cookie?

Comment: developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/storage/cookies Find the name in the cookie table.

Answer (score 0):

**Cypress 13** has **[session](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/session) handling**.

example:

```
cy.session(
    [user, password],
    () => {
        cy.visit('/auth/login');

        type('#user_name', user);
        type('#user_password', password);

        cy.get('#user_login_submit').click();
        cy.url().should('contain', '/first_page_after_login');
    },
    {
        cacheAcrossSpecs: true,
    },
);
```

Answer (score -1):

this works for me:
on cypress.config.ts, i added `testIsolation`:

```
e2e: {
testIsolation: false
},
```

and on the test file: samplepage.cy.js

```
before(() => {
    const token = window.sessionStorage.getItem('orcUser')
    if (!token) cy.login(path)
})
beforeEach(() => {        
    cy.visit(path)
        .location('pathname', { timeout: 7000 })
        .should('eq', path);
})
```

i have `before() method` which trigger only once before the `beforeEach method`